# Create a Hibernate schema not automatically, but with SQL script

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

In my project I use h2 in memory database, and I want it to be created not by Hibernate, but with by a SQL script. Here is my hibernate.properties

I made

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
```

**none** to disable autocreation of database, and added

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=schema.sql,insert-users.sql
```

**schema.sql** contains SQL code to create schema, and then to insert-users.sql and it contains the initial data.

The project builds successfully, but when I try to hit database, I get 
a **`Table <tablename> not found`** exception.

Comment: hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.connection.driver.class=org.h2.Driver
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:h2:memhelpdeskdb
hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=schema.sql,insert-users.sql

Comment: Here are my properties, I don't know why, but I cant add it to the post...

Comment: Corrected mispelling in title. Highlighted some pertinent words. Changed error message to display as code and thus display the full message (<tablename> was missing as <> are used to indicate quoted text).

Comment: How are you getting on with the answers below, Fairy? One was posted on the same day, and one was posted the day after your question.

Answer (score 3):

Since Hibernate won't do this for you unless you use `create` or `create-drop` hbm2ddl, there are other ways to achieve what you want.

## Specialized tools

There are tools that are created specifically for this: [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/), [LiquiBase](http://www.liquibase.org/). These are often configured to be run when the app is deployed and allow you to version DB scheme. They are applicable not only for testing (and mainly - not for testing), but for production as well. They can ensure that the scheme on all your envs is the same. If you use these tools, then it's better to set `hbm2ddl` to `validate`.

## Spring's support

Less widespread way is to use [Spring's support](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch12s08.html) for embedded DBs:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql"/>
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

## Data for testing

If the intention is to create *data for testing* (not scheme), then it's better to create entities and use your DAO/Repository layer to persist those in tests. This way you don't duplicate mechanisms of persisting data.

Answer (score 0):

Two comments from the [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html) are relevant here:

```
This is useful for testing or demoing: by adding INSERT statements for example you can populate your database with a minimal set of data when it is deployed.
```

and

```
These statements are only executed if the schema is created ie if hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is set to create or create-drop.
```

I'm not too sure that the import functionality will do what you want it to do.